# how can i create a copy from google sheet with my script to another one?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a problem with a googlesheet copy.

In fact, when I copy a google sheet with script to another one, I must create the trigger again.

After creating it, my script is working properly again.

My main problem is a lambda user who create a copy of my template, and I can't ask to my users to create the triger again.

So How can I create a copy with script without create the trigger again ?

Kind regard

Nicolas

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

A trigger must be created by a user, it's a matter of security (since triggers run under authority of the user who creates it, he has to know what he's doing and authorize it explicitly).

But triggers [can be created programaticall](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#newTrigger(String))y so your user will only have to call this function from a menu item.

You can even create a small popup that would show up on opening of the sheet to explain what to do.

Even the "worst" lambda user should be able to get through this.

Comment: Hi Serge, I will try it your way Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just dealt with the same issue, I basically did what Serge suggested. Only instead of creating a browser/menu item. I created a button and assigned my install trigger script to it. This way it's mindless, they only have to click a button, it gets authorization then installs your trigger as you intended.